# Saving an Excel file: You do not have the correct permissions. Contact the server administrator

Tags: error, excel

A user is attempting to open an excel file from a SP 2010 library, make edits, and save it back.  when clicking save, he gets this error message in a popup window:  You do not have the correct permissions. Contact the server administrator.

It appears randomly.  At times, he can save the file with no errors.  other times this message pops up.

He is a site owner with a custom permission level.  Its basically Full Control with the options to create subsites and change look & feel taken away.  He has this same permission on the site and library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have item level permissions in the library?

Comment: Is the SharePoint site on another domain? I.E. are you crossing network boundaries to reach it?

Comment: This is a problem with the keys of Excel on the Registry.

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously something wrong with this users rights. If I were u I would remove him from the library. Then add him again and make sure the correct rights are applied.